# When loading Ubuntu from USB programs aren't there

Tags: playonlinux

Basically, I'm trying to play Hearthstone at work, but don't want to download it onto the computers there. I've put Ubuntu on a usb and have no issue getting into it from the usb at work. I know I have to use playonlinux to get Hearthstone on ubuntu and I know how to do that. So two questions:

1. Is there a way I could simply boot Ubuntu from my USB and have hearthstone already there on its desktop ready to play?
2. If not, and I have to go through playonlinux, does the computer itself recognize that I'm downloading something? Not sure if that makes sense. Basically, I'll probably get in shit if I download something on a work computer. But if I'm in Ubuntu (off a USB) and I download, is that traceable?

Thanks! PS, I'm a newbie when it comes to any of this, so plain english please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure for all intents and purposes the USB is untraceable. If you do not change any BIOS settings to show that you’re booting off a USB stick once in a while you’re safe. Wouldn’t download anything though as the computer is functioning just like normal, it is simply running a OS from a different source namely your USB, and therefore your IP address is still traceable - Now for saving a configuration on a USB I’m pretty sure you can create a persistent file when creating you USB. That should save all changes you make to the USB while using it.
[image]